# Error on basic auth using axios

Tags: rest, vue.js, basic-authentication, axios, kong

I am using kong for my basic authentication for my API.
It works perfectly when using Postman.
But it keeps throwing up an error whenever I want to integrate it in my app using axios. Please help me out here. Thanks!

Below are my codes:

My main.js file:

```
var app5 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-5',
  data: {
    message: ''
  },
  methods: {
    getQuote() {
      var config = { url: '/allquotes',
      baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/',
       headers: {'Host': 'quotesapi.com/'},
        withCredentials: false,
        auth: {
        username: 'Aladdin',
        password: 'OpenSesame'
        },
        responseType: 'json'
      }

      axios.get(config)
      .then(
        response => {
                    this.message =  (response.data.quotes[0].quotes);
      })
      .catch(function (error){
        console.log('Error on Authentication');
      });
    }
  }
})
```

The console error message:
 [console error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p3Co.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEGv8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter for `localhost/part2/ /!\ This one /!\` is a raw object.

I think you have to do: `JSON.Stringify(youObject)` before calling the backend, or send it by POST method like:  `axios.post(url, data)`

Comment: Thanks !!. I tried the json.stringify() but it complained it didn't recognize the function. I console.logged the error and I have edited my question to include the snapshot of the error.